# Specification of use of overloaded function

Tags: c++, overloading

```
template <typename T>
class Obj {
public:
Obj<T>* doThis();
const Obj<T>* doThis() const {// return normal version of doThis()}
};
```

In the example, I want the const version of `doThis()` to return normal version of `doThis()`. I don't think it's ok to just put `return doThis()` in definition of const version of `doThis()` because C++ may think this is recursion of const version of `doThis()`.

Is there any way to explicitly tell C++ which function to call?

Comment: Don't. The `const` means something here. It's a promise that the object will not be modified during the invocation of the function. If you call the non-const version you'll potentially break this promise. That can only cause problems.

Comment: Now, if you want to do it the other way around, i.e. make the non-const overload call the const one, that would be fine and won't break any promises.

Comment: Of course there is a way. I was commenting on the direction you wish to do the code sharing. One is error prone, the other is much less so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Story Teller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817643/storyteller-unslander-monica) mentioned in the comment, don't do this, because this can lead to UB, e.g., in this simple case:

```
const Obj<int> obj;
obj.doThis(); // UB since you will have to const_cast<Obj<int>&>(obj).
```

The proper thing is to do it the other way:

```
template <typename T>
class Obj {
public:
    Obj<T>* doThis() {
        return const_cast<Obj<T>*>(std::as_const(*this).doThis());
    }
    const Obj<T>* doThis() const { /* Actual implementation. */ }
};
```

Note that this implies that the return value of `doThis() const` can be safely `const_cast` back to `Obj<T>*` (e.g., if you return `this` in `doThis`, this is safe).

If you cannot implement `doThis()` in the `const`-qualified version, then your code is probably flawed.